# how would and where would I take user input for my needle and haystacks variables in this code

Tags: java

I am doing this for project and the directions are as followed:
Write   a   program,    StringSearch,   that    takes   in  two strings as  program arguments,  prints  the 
number  of  occurrences of  the first   string  in  the second  string, and prints  the position    of  the 
first   occurrence  of  the first   string  in  the second  string.
I  am still a novice and have borrowed chunks of this code from a textbook and don't understand yet how to integrate it into the code I have written. I know I am not really asking a specific question I just don't understand how to get my code to accomplish the task.

```
 package StringSearch;

/**
 *
 * @author devan
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchString {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nargs = args.length;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Please enter value for needle:");
      String needle;
      needle = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Please enter value for haystack:");
      String haystack = scanner.nextLine();
    if(nargs < 2) {
System.out.println("Insufficient arguments provided");
System.out.println("Usage is: java SearchString needle haystack");
    } 
    else {
      System.out.println(searchString(args[0].toCharArray(),args[1].toCharArray()));
      System.out.println(getFrequency(args[0].toCharArray(),args[1].toCharArray()));
    }
  }
  public static int searchString(char[] needle, char[] haystack) {
    int nsize = needle.length;
    int hsize = haystack.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < hsize; i++) {
     int j;

     for(j = 0; j < nsize; j++) {
      if(i+j >= hsize) {
        break;
      }
      if(needle[j] != haystack[i+j]) {
        break; 
      }
     }
     if(j == nsize) {
       return i+1;
     }
   }
   return -1;
 }

 public static int getFrequency(char[] needle, char[] haystack) {
   int freq = 0;
   int nsize = needle.length;
   int hsize = haystack.length;
   for(int i = 0; i < hsize; i++) {
     int j;
     for(j = 0; j < nsize; j++) {
       if(i+j >= hsize) {
         break;
       }
       if(needle[j] != haystack[i+j]) {
         break;
       }
     }
     if(j == nsize) {
       freq++;
     }
   }
   if(freq == 0)
     return -1;
   else
     return freq;
 }
   }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

The typical format for command line argument prompts is,

error message
Usage: correct usage

so the code would look something like

```
if(nargs < 2) {
    System.out.println("Insufficient arguments provided");
    System.out.println("Usage is: java SearchString needle haystack");
} ...
```

if you wish to have the user input data interactivly then use a Scanner

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter value for needle:");
String needle = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Please enter value for haystack:");
String haystack = scanner.nextLine();
```